# como puedo agregar un nuevo campo a mi modelo laravel?

Tags: laravel

Hola buenas necesito ayuda con un problema que tengo, este es el siguiente:
trabajo con laravel 5.8 y tengo un modelo el cual es el siguiente:

```
class ProductosJumpsellerweb extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productosjumpsellerweb';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_ai';

    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $fillable = [
    'id','sku','name','stock','price','parent_id'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Este fue creado hace varios meses, hoy nace la necesidad de agregar una nueva columna a mi tabla y el modelo quedaría así según yo:

```
class ProductosJumpsellerweb extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productosjumpsellerweb';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_ai';

    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $fillable = [
    'id','sku','name','stock','price','parent_id','url'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

El problema es que en mi controlador no me aparece mi nuevo campo o tampoco se como poder verlo, quedo atento muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿La migración ya esta hecha? ¿Es decir, la BD ya está actualizada?

Comment: Por favor explica mejor tu duda, ¿no aparece en alguna consulta que haces?

Comment: tienes que verificar si hicistes la migracion o existe la tabla en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realizas cambios en laravel la cache todavía tiene los datos de la anterior configuración por favor utiliza los siguientes comandos.

```
sudo php artisan config:clear
sudo php artisan cache:clear
sudo php artisan config:cache
```